# Android: at are the permission rules of file read and write files

Tags: android, file-io, permissions

### Question

// There is the test code I used at the end here

I would be very happy to have two questions answered:

1.) What are the present official policies about read and write file permissions?

2.) How do I get read and write permissions of user work files on the /sdcard?

I have a feeling this is all bout API versions and not unit types.

It looks like the permissions have changed quite a lot during the development of different Android versions and the way to handle them. Articles/questions about them are spread for many years and obviously most of them are obsolete and deprecated, but still there in the stackoverflow environment. The changes can be read about in version reviews etc. But even the main developer support site seems to be obsolete and deprecated like http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

### Scope

I am making a bookkeeping accounting app in Android from a working Win32 program in C. New user Android interface.

For this type of applications certainly user files are to be transferred between users be public like word processing files. Should be downloaded over ftp or html but also by attaching an Android unit to a PC and just drag'n drop them. And in fact a lot of Apps do read and write files in like the /sdcard and /sdcard/download locations.

Without /sdcard write/read, a large number of application types are not possible under the Android OS. And this is especially odd when the Android x86 project made it possible to equip cheap netbooks with keyboards and no touchscreen with Android OS and very smooth user and sales opportunities (a true Windows-killer alternative). And very efficient travelling office tool. There are for instance good MS Office competitors and just a matter of time until there is an official Android MS Office available. Internet, social media and mail is there and what else do people use?

### Results

Using 10.1 WXGA tablet emulator API-23 and a Samsung TAB3 7' tablet API-17.

Running it on internal storage no problem reading, writing and deleting files (however huge problems getting test user data files to the internal storage from outside (however the emulator allowed it with adb-commands)).

Running on external storage it is possible to read files but not write files.

Running on the /sdcard/download or /sdcard folders the emulator (API-23) refused both read and writing  but the TAB3 allowed reading but refused writing.

One remarkable thing is that files denied to be written (over or appended) are possible to delete with the file.delete() call as soon as they are possible to read?

### Tests

I started with jni ANSI C file functions. But to make it simpler and easier to use Android experience from the past I changed to use Java code instead, testing. It was a general environment issue I thought and not a jni/C-issue.

Certainly there is a manifest statement made: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

First I got three calls to get the storage sdcard, internal and external storages for different use of an app. Then combining them with a local file name. By changing the storage I am able to test each environment on different test units/emulators.

Testing in steps: 
- Writing a file
- Reading a file
- Deleting a file
- Testing permissions 
- Document them in a text array put on the test units screen

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView  tv = new TextView(this);

    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File  internal = getFilesDir();
    File  external = getExternalCacheDir();
    File file = new File(internal ,"hello.txt");

    String string = "Hello world!";
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput(file.getName(),0);
        outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    text.append(file);
    text.append('\n');
    if(isExternalStorageWritable())
        text.append("Writeable");
    else
        text.append("Non-Writeable");
    text.append('\n');
    if(isExternalStorageReadable())
        text.append("Readable");
    else
        text.append("Non-Readable");
    text.append('\n');
    String permission = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";
    if(checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        text.append("WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
    else
        text.append("Non-WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
    text.append('\n');

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    }

    file.delete();

    tv.setText(text.toString());

    setContentView(tv);
}
```

Comment: Note that `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` doesn't actually return a directory on the SD card - it is more external as in available to all apps than actually removable storage.

Comment: You haven't mentioned how you've handled permissions: do you have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your manifest? Storage is a [runtime permission](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html) on API 23 devices if your targetSdkVersion is 23 - do you request the permission at runtime before doing your test?

Comment: I have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the manifest, tried with them both but obviously only WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE because them both set read rights. The Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory delivers the sdcard, and there is a regular external and internal alternative too. By the File file = new File(internal ,"hello.txt"); I switch between the storage location by changing internal to for instance sdcard.

Comment: Even this sample fails http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/writeSD.html writing and gets a negative response at if(checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) even though if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) is positive. (this sample did actually not test its writing by reading it). It looks like being an WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE issue but the manifest stuff isn't what is wrong. Must be something completely different, and came up with later Android versions.